# JSON in jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JS skills are pretty poor, and I'm trying to hack this thing together from tutorials. With that said, I can't figure out why this isn't working.

How do I pass and reference the JSON object in the each loop?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonData = '["{ staffid :41, firstname :Joe, lastname :Blow}", "{ staffid :42, firstname :Lucy, lastname :Goosey}"]';
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each(jsonParsed, function(index, value){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type:'get',
        async:false,
        url: 'genpdf.php?staffid=' + value.staffid,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#status").append("<li>Successfully generated PDF for " +     value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ")</li>");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $("#status").append("<li>PDF genetration failed for " + value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ") with status (" + textStatus + ") and error (" + errorThrown + ")</li>");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around object literals `{}`
Try http://jsonlint.com to verify your data

Comment: why are you parsing the object? why can't you create a proper object like `var jsonData = [{ staffid :41, firstname :Joe, lastname :Blow}, { staffid :42, firstname :Lucy, lastname :Goosey}];` then `jQuery.each(jsonData, function(index, value){});`

Comment: You don't have any JSON objects. Your JSON text consists of an array of strings. Those strings are text representations of JavaScript object literals, but not JSON objects.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: It looks like a test case to get the parsing working. The JSON will probably be read in from a file or server call or something.

Comment: For this particular example, you can just reference the `jsonParsed` variable directly, with no need to pass it around. The `jsonData` and `jsonParsed` variables are in the global scope.

Comment: Why are you using `async:false,`?  That *will* lock up the browser until the AJAX call is done!

Comment: Also, do you really want to make a separate AJAX call for every single item in your JSON object? I'd try to figure out a way to combine them into a single AJAX call, if I were you.

Comment: Rocket: I've explained my use of async: false below. Unfortunately it seems to be a necessary evil. I don't know why.

Charlie: if I could get FPDF to loop so that I could produce more than one PDF per PHP script executed, I would do that. That doesn't appear to be possible, though, so this was the most immediate solution that didn't require finding another PDF library to do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonData = '["{ staffid :41, firstname :Joe, lastname :Blow}", "{ staffid :42, firstname :Lucy, lastname :Goosey}"]'
```

This JSON string does not contain what you think it does.  When parsed, you will have an array of 2 objects.  If you wanted an array of objects, it should look like this:

```
var jsonData = '[{"staffid": 41, "firstname": "Joe", "lastname": "Blow"}, {"staffid": 42, "firstname": "Lucy", "lastname": "Goosey"}]'
```

When you parse this, it should work as you expect.

Also, why do you even have a JSON string here in the first place?  Why not use a JavaScript array/object literal.

```
var data = [{staffid: 41, firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Blow"}, {staffid: 42, firstname: "Lucy", lastname: "Goosey"}];
```

P.S. I *highly* suggest **not** using `async:false`.  That will make the browser lock up until the AJAX call is done.  You will not be able to interact with the page (and possibly the browser) until it's done.  That's not great UX at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Yep, my JSON was malformed and I was unnecessarily parsing.

I am using async false because if I set it to true then only the first PDF generates successfully (and the other AJAX calls get a 401).

Seems to be an idiosyncrasy of the FPDF library. Either that or just another stupid thing I'm doing!

Answer (score 1):

you are preparing wrong json string. It should be

```
var jsonData = '[{ "staffid" :41, "firstname":"Joe", "lastname":"Blow"}, { "staffid":42, "firstname":"Lucy", "lastname":"Goosey"}]';
```

And if you preparing json string on javascript then you should direct use array object for eg.

```
var jsonData = [{ "staffid" :41, "firstname":"Joe", "lastname":"Blow"}, { "staffid":42, "firstname":"Lucy", "lastname":"Goosey"}];
```

then you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, I believe the main source of your trouble is the formatting of the JSON. I have modified your code slightly and set it up on [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/Vtz2v/).

### HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

### JavaScript

```
var jsonData = '[{"staffid": 41, "firstname": "Joe", "lastname": "Blow"}, {"staffid": 42, "firstname": "Lucy", "lastname": "Goosey"}]';
console.log(jsonData);
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $list = $("ul#list");
    jQuery.each(jsonParsed, function(index, value) {
        console.log(index,value);
        $list.append("<li>index = " + index +
                     ", staffid = " + value.staffid +
                     ", firstname = " + value.firstname +
                     ", lastname = " + value.lastname +
                     "</li>");
        /* 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            url: 'genpdf.php?staffid=' + value.staffid,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#status").append("<li>Successfully generated PDF for " +     value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ")</li>");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $("#status").append("<li>PDF genetration failed for " + value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ") with status (" + textStatus + ") and error (" + errorThrown + ")</li>");
            }
        });
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just drop the data structure into the code as an object literal? What good does the `.parse()` step do, in other words?

Comment: @Pointy, I believe stoo is just using that as a stub/fixture to make sure the other code works. In the comments for the original question it said that the data will likely be coming from some other source in the future.

Comment: Both correct. As I said, I was hacking this together quickly from multiple tutorials and forum posts and I really wasn't sure what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I've upvoted all of you, because you were all correct. I got it working eventually, though probably not optimally.

Some of you mentioned async:false being a bad idea. I'm well aware of that but if I set it to true only the first AJAX call is actually successful and the rest get a 401 response!

The genpdf.php script calls a free PHP PDF library called FPDF, which seems to have some idiosyncrasies. Ultimately, the only way I could find to get it to output multiple PDF files was to call it multiple times.

In the end, this is what I did (involved installing the mysqlnd driver for PHP so I could use fetch_all which made it cleaner):

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT staffid, firstname, lastname FROM Staff")) { // get staffid for user if it exists
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    die("Prepared Statement Error: $mysqli->error");
}
$resultJSON = json_encode($resultArray);
?>

<div>
<ul id="status"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonData = <?=$resultJSON?>;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function(index, value){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type:'get',
        async:false,
        url: 'genpdf.php?staffid=' + value.staffid,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#status").append("<li>Successfully generated PDF for " + value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ")</li>");
            },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $("#status").append("<li>PDF generation failed for " + value.firstname + " " + value.lastname + " (StaffID: " + value.staffid + ") with status (" + textStatus + ") and error (" + errorThrown + ")</li>");
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You do not need to set `async: false` to correct the problem you described. You just need to change how you sequence the `jQuery.ajax` calls. Instead of firing them all off in an each loop, you could have the each loop add them to a queue and have the callback start the next item in the queue. This way other things (e.g. timers, events, ...) won't stall out because your code is hogging the thread. In other words, setting `async: false` in order to make your code "work" is a hack not a solution.

Comment: iX3: Thanks. That's helpful. I'll try to implement the queue instead of using async:false.